# howto configure rights on webserver for successful bzr repository

Tags: webserver, bazaar, rights-management

I'm trying to get a better workflow with bzr between deploy server and local development machine.

Web server running as www-user and bzr-login with local account, wdev.
at server groups are setup, www-user: www-user,wdev and vice versa.

For simplicity, urgent bugfixes are fixed in trunk at server through ssh.

What would be the recommended setup? Trunk in /home/wdev?

Should the deployment be a trunk or branch?

Currently, I have to su root to commit, which puzzels me.. I can "su www-data" and have read/write access. Still, the webserver still doesn't have write permissions with php.
Current solution is chown:ing everything to www-data, a dislikable solutions since any merge
would blur new files with wdev-ownership.

Thankful for any basic howto regarding prefered setup

(this is more or less a x-post from https://serverfault.com/questions/299436/directory-rights-with-webserver-and-bzr but didn't get much response there).

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trunk I assume you mean the master-branch ? With distributed revision control systems there is no distinction between a trunk and a branch it is just a convention, so just organise them so they are convenient for you.

Maybe you can use sticky bits:
http://michael.lustfield.net/content/creating-your-own-bazaar-server
I have not had it working nicely ever (maybe I did it wrong), so I use a cronjob to fixup permissions hourly.

If you use a [smart server](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/server.html) all the users commit through 1 os user, so the permissions are handled at another level.

Comment: Ah, thanks for reply. Bash and cron are great but no need for it would  be even better... ;-|